# if when i click the map marker that should show the shop name and other details in the snippet, geo map with algolia

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I am displaying the hits as a list and map. I had done with list when i click the single hit that will the info or name in `Toast` message. But In the map if i click the `marker`, of snippet not showing any info or any data recording the appropriate hit's data(Asume shop name). This not only end with `android and geo marker`, And also link with **Algolia hits**. please help me and i am suffering from last four days.

```
@Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(12.670913552202967,78.6066235229373),20);
            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            View v =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hits_item,null);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you add the markers? In order to display something when you click on the marker, you need to set the `title` and the `snippet`. 
Example:

```
    final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    try {
        marker.title(jsonObject.getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {}
    try {
        final String location = jsonObject.getString("smart_location");
        final String price = jsonObject.getString("price_formatted");
        marker.snippet(price + " - " + location);
    } catch (JSONException e) {}
    try {
        final Double latitude = jsonObject.getDouble("lat");
        final Double longitude= jsonObject.getDouble("lng");
        marker.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
    } catch (JSONException e) {}

    mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I have same code in model class (As in the sample project format for android). My doubt is pass data to next activity when i clicking the marker.(like name of the shop or register_id). where i use intent.

Comment: That's a different question that you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744809/if-i-click-the-marker-then-move-to-next-activity-detail-of-the-shop-with-algol). I will reply there.

Comment: Hi Thofiq, welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to accept/upvote the answers that solve your problem, to reward the person who takes time to help you and to let other people know this was helpful ;)